# Angular.js watch only on particular object property

Tags: javascript, object, angularjs, watch, angularjs-scope

Basically I want this http://plnkr.co/edit/3yfXbo1c0llO40HZ8WNP?p=preview but watch doesn't fire when I change something..

I know that this would have worked

```
$scope.$watch('stuff', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(oldVal, newVal);

}, true);
```

But since I want to do some summing up inside the watches and I don't want to unnecessarily loop thru or re-sum values that did not change..

*//edit - 
note that the plnkr example is just an extraction from the actual app, where you can add and remove rows and much more, like modifying the total number(sum of somethings and somethingelses) from another input outside the ng-repeat..*

Comment: There is no `$scope.stuff.something` variable, so you can't $watch that.

Comment: @Stewie So I should either watch the whole `stuff` or rather have my summing functions inside some onchange/onkeyup event, is that right?

Comment: Can you explain/show what you mean exactly by 'summing'?

Comment: I want a sum of `something` and `somethingelse`, now when `something` changes, it would be unnecessarily to sum `somethingelse` as well

Comment: need to loop through whole object to get sum of one property, so what differnce will it make to sum other property at same time?

Comment: @charlietfl well ideally I'd want to loop thru and sum only on init and then listen to changes and do something like -oldVal +newVal

Comment: I'd say just watch the whole `stuff` and keep away from [premature optimization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/75390/why-should-i-care-about-micro-performance-and-efficency/75466#75466).

Comment: Will the properties be changing because of input fields like you show in your Plunker? If so, then you can use ng-change or (maybe better) write a "blur" directive to only update the associated sum when an input field changes or blurs.

Answer (score 6):

I would not do a watch as depending on how large your array could be, might be very taxing. Instead I would just create a filter:

HTML:

```
Sum of something is: {{ stuff | sum:'something' }}<br/>
Sum of somethingelse is: {{ stuff | sum:'somethingelse' }}
```

Javascript:

```
.filter("sum", function(){
    return function(input, params){
        var totalSum = 0;
        for(var x = 0; x < input.length; x++){
            totalSum += input[x][params];
        }
        return totalSum;
    }
})
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/p6kM3ampSuMXnwqcteYd?p=preview

Comment: This uses less watches and let's angular do more of the grunt work. Having a loop that sets up a lot of watch's as in the other examples will only slow down your program as your array grows in size.

Comment: If you're only showing the sum, not using it internally, then I believe this is the best approach. The only thing I would do different, is that I wouldn't use a `filter`. You can simply set the binding to `{{stuff.something + stuff.somethingelse}}`. This way you will grant the value will always change when one or another changes, at the minimum watch cost.

Comment: I don't think you can use the binding you suggested, stuff is an array, not an object.

Comment: This solution will actually watch the whole object.

Comment: @ganaraj do you have a source for that? I'd like to read up more on it.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it wrong. The binding would be inside the `ng-repeat`, with `row` instead of `stuff`: `{{row.something + row.somethingelse}}`.

Comment: So how would that do the total sum then, this would just add the two columns together and repeat it.

15074, 15070... I don't think that's what they are looking for.

Comment: @MathewBerg: It does watch the whole object, or else it wont get notified when something changes inside it, isnt it? $watch can also watch functions which means it actually executes the function and cache's its return value. Then each time scope changes, it runs the function to see if the return value of the function is different. Well, what you are looking for is kind of here.  
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L1084

Comment: @ganaraj interesting, do you know the resource hit of doing filters vs having a watch? I notice this filter's watch (your link) doesn't do a dirty check.

Comment: So wait, it's internally all the same as $watch then isn't it? Now I actually am using the sum internally later on, so $watch is still better then isn't it?

Comment: OOooh God! I understood it wrong. He need the sums of `something`'s and the sum of `somethingelse`'s. I believe the best solution is either watch them individually (if possible to know when the array changed) or the entire object. The filter solution would cause the `for` to happen on EVERY digest cycle, not only when it change (this is how filters work). I believe it would be good to test the performance impact as @MathewBerg questioned.

Comment: Here is an overview of how the filter solution works. You are using interpolation which actually puts a $watch on the interpolated object. Each time the interpolated object changes, an interpolation function is called ( which call's the filter's ). Its actually not a deep watch on the object, but it seems like a scope level watch ( not really sure about this! ) which means each time anything in the scope changes this function is called atleast once. So, technically its even costlier than watching that single object.

Comment: Depends on how watch works on a scope. If what you're saying is true, it would be no different as the $watch within the controller would get checked each time the scope changes as well would it not?

Comment: Another thing is that when I'm watching on the whole object, watch also fires on add, where it, since I'm adding an empty row, doesn't need to be fired.

Answer (score 4):

I am smiling all over the place after I came up with this solution for your problem. Not only is this solution going to watch individual objects, it also is not going to do a complete loop through the rest of the objects for the summation.

http://plnkr.co/edit/oPWobcLLtJlxs5vjTYyc?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.stuff = STUFF;
  var i;
  $scope.sumOfSomething = 0;
  $scope.sumOfSomethingElse = 0;

  for(i=0;i < $scope.stuff.length;i++ ){
    $scope.$watch('stuff['+i+'].something', function (newVal,oldVal) {
      // happens when the watch is registered.
      if(oldVal === newVal){
        $scope.sumOfSomething += +newVal;
        return;
      }
      if(newVal){
        $scope.sumOfSomething += + (newVal - oldVal);
      }
    });

    $scope.$watch('stuff['+i+'].somethingelse', function (newVal,oldVal) {
      // happens when the watch is registered. 
      if(oldVal === newVal){
        $scope.sumOfSomethingElse += +newVal;
        return;
      }

      if(newVal){
        $scope.sumOfSomethingElse += + (newVal - oldVal);
      }

    });  
  }
});
```

By the way I dont know how optimal this solution is going to be if you have a large number of objects in `STUFF`. Also, this wont work as is if the number of objects in `STUFF` is going to change. What we are basically doing is using the dirty checking loop of angular to do our summation for us.

Also notice the order of newVal and oldVal in the watch listener. Your order is wrong.

Comment: this solution as I see it does not add support for adding elements to 'stuff'

Comment: @martinpaulucci I have already mentioned that . 

SEE : 

Also, this wont work as is, if the number of objects in STUFF is going to change.

Comment: This fixes the original poster's mistake of watching 'stuff.something' instead of 'stuff[i].something' and answers the question in the title of this page: "Angular.js watch only on particular object property".  The issues mentioned that relate to watching individual elements of an array are all valid but that's not part of the question that got me to this page.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since `$watch()` takes an angular expression you can use a custom watcher function. In your case the easiest way to watch for changes is simply to add up all the fields you're interested in then return a single number which is nice and efficient for angular and your sum will be ready to render.

```
var sumThings = function(obj, field) {
  var val = 0;
  obj.forEach(function(o) {
    val += parseInt(o[field]);
  });
  return val;
};

$scope.$watch(function() { return sumThings($scope.stuff, "something")}, function (newVal, oldVal) {    //console.log("watchExpression('something') fired!", oldVal, newVal);
  $scope.somethingSum = newVal;
});

$scope.$watch(function() { return sumThings($scope.stuff, "somethingelse")}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
  $scope.somethingelseSum = newVal;
});
```

Basically, by doing your summation you're doing your own dirty checking. It'll be more efficient than `$watch(STUFF, true)` if your objects are more complex than you've shown here.

#### Your updated plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/d7CvERu3XGkub4l6f1yw?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I got it, you just want to sum `something` with `somethingelse` of the inner objects when they change. And you don't want to loop through all the other inner objects if the change is in one of them.

Well, your `$watch` isn't firing for there is no `stuff.property`, and there is no patterns like `stuff.*.something`.

If you know the moment the objects gets pushed or pulled from the array, than you can apply a separately `$scope.$watch(object, function(){}, true)` before/after inserting each one to the array. If you don't know this moment, than you will need to `$watch` the entire array, and when a change happens, run all deregistration functions and `$watch` them all again, one by one.

Anyway, a loop in nowadays browsers is pretty fast, and except you're doing heavy calculations and you have millions of objects (what would have been a memory problem already) you'll probably be good with it. So, an effort to `$watch` them all separately is only necessary if you have really heavy calculations, that could comprise the system performance.

Comment: I'm sure there won't be more than 100 objects inside `stuff`. So you are saying that I should just stick with watch on the whole `stuff` instead of doing what @garanaj suggested.

Comment: The problem with adding a ,true at the end of a watch is that it checks the entire object/array. This will become very taxing as the array grows in size.

Comment: If you know when the array changes, than it would be better the approach of adding a separately `$watch` to them. Anyway, if your objects are not too dense, I see no performance issue `$watch`ing 100 items. But stick with separately watches if you know when it changes.